# Visual studio setup project setting pre-requisite .Net 2.0?

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, installation, setup-project

I have a visual studio install setup project in which I want to specify that pre-requisite is .Net 2.0 
When I click properties-> pre-requisite

[image]
it shows only .Net framework 3.5 / client profile and .Net framework 4.0/client profile and other components but not .Net 2.0

The second part is will the installer fail if pre-reqs are not met or install them automatically ?

Thanks,

Comment: Time marches on.  The .NET 2.0 installer, a 7 year old program, is no longer available.  It was removed from the Microsoft downloads a couple of months ago.  It is a dead parrot.  It isn't stunned, it is not pining for the fjords.  It is no more.  It has ceased to be.  It is bereft of life.  It rests in peace.  Tick 3.5 SP1.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks :) enough to convince me. One little query. If I tick 3.5 will the installer still install 3.5 if 4.0 is already on the client machine and not 3.5 ?

Comment: Yes, 4.0 is not a substitute for 3.5, not without a .config file.

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the properties for the solution you can select which version of the .NET framework you use. Note this is for the non Express versions only.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx

Furthermore Microsoft keeps itself in business by only making VS backwards but not forwards compatible with future .NEzt versions.

To create an installer you needmtomcreatemamDeployment project and specify the dependendcies.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324733

Comment: I am using VS 2010 pro, the properties->pre-requisites show .Net framework 3.5 onwards does not show .Net 2.0 . My project needs 2.0 not 3.5 etc. SO how can I resolve that